# Принцип работы Аудио звонков(не видео) Skype, кто знает про WEBRTC, SIP телефонию? И почему разговоры в скайп бесплатные

Tags: sip, skype, webrtc, whatsapp, телефония

Интересует принцип работы аудиовызовов в Skype - каким образом происходит вызов одного аккаунта другому. Я предполагаю что при регистрации нужно указать и подтвердить свой мобильный номер, после чего будет доступны звонки посредством SIP телефонии? (виртуальной АТС)
Или как это может работать?
Слышал недавно новость что в Skype можно вообще не регистрироваться, и делать аудио-видеозвонки.
Буду благодарен за ответ.
Еще лучше будет если вы ответите, можно ли совершать Аудиозвонки с сайта на сайт? 
WEBRTC

Comment: Тут вопросов аж шесть штук, и четыре из них требуют обстоятельных ответов. Не спешите. Может быть, зададите вопрос в виде задачи, требующей решения ("Я хотел бы  бесплатно без регистрации и СМС звонить из своего скайпа на сайт УФНС. Как этого добиться?")?

Answer (score 1):

Skype не раскрывает как он работает. Или Микрософт не раскрывает)) 
На сколько я знаю, у них собственный протокол.

Совершать звонки в скайпе можно только зарегистрированным и авторизованным пользователям.

Аудиозвонки с сайта на сайт совершать можно) всё верно webRTC